# digits in string

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am validating string with some standards. It should start wih R- and proj_nm as a variable and project_cd as numbers and any desc
i.e, R-${PROJ_NM}-[Numbers]-anything

```
if [[ $var == "R-"${PROJ_NM}"-"[[:digit:]]"-"* ]] ; then echo "Naming convention is in correct format" else echo "Not in correct format" exit 1 fi
```

I am getting output as not in correct format.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a few examples of input, what you want to get from that input and what you actually get from that input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to have one or more numbers (you said number**s**), then you need `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]` for two, `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]` for three etc.

```
if [[ $var == "R-"${PROJ_NM}"-"[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]"-"* ]] ; then 
    echo "Naming convention is in correct format"
else 
    echo "Not in correct format" 
fi
```

But you can simplify your quotes a little:

```
if [[ $var == "R-${PROJ_NM}-"[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]"-"* ]] ; then 
    echo "Naming convention is in correct format"
else 
    echo "Not in correct format" 
fi
```

Alternatively, with newer bash versions, you can use regular expressions:

```
if [[ $var =~ ^R-${PROJ_NM}-[0-9]+- ]] ; then 
    echo "Naming convention is in correct format"
else 
    echo "Not in correct format" 
fi
```